# Error while executing with subprocess

Tags: python, bash, shell

I'm trying to execute a shell command via Python code, but I'm not capable to understand why it is failing.

When printing the command and pasting it to the shell to try executing it directly works perfectly fine, that's the strange part.

From Python I'm getting the following:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `/DATA/NGS/ngs_software/bioinfoSoftware/bwa_current/bwa mem ... --threads 4 -T /tmp/samTemp -'
```

Is there anything I'm missing? My code looks like this, where 'cmd' is the string with the command. The OS is a CentOS with a bash shell:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = process.stdout.readline()
out = out.decode("utf-8").strip('\n')
```

Comment: What is the command?

Comment: `shell to try executing it directly works perfectly` idle hold your app but `who hold your app on outside ?`

Comment: @chepner gave me the correct answer, it was a substitution that was not working. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command contains a process substitution, but `Popen` runs its command using `/bin/sh`. When run as `/bin/sh`, though, `bash` does not allow process substitutions. You can explicitly request that the command be run with `bash` using the `executable` option.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Awesome!, that does work, didn't know about that. Thank you indeed for your help :)

Comment: Thanks for that executable option... didn't know it existed... I was having an error with redirection via <<< and this fixed it